# sed: How to replace all content in a multi-line pattern?

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I have to create a sql script from another altering their content. Eg.

```
SELECT value INTO val FROM table WHERE condition;
SELECT value2 INTO val2 FROM table WHERE condition1
                                   OR condition2;
```

So I have tried

```
sed 's/FROM .*;/;/g'
```

But it's returns this

```
SELECT value INTO val ;
SELECT value2 INTO val2 FROM table WHERE condition1
                                   OR condition2;
```

instead of this, which is what I need

```
SELECT value INTO val ;
SELECT value2 INTO val2 ;
```

Any ideas? Basically what I want to do is remove all that is included among 'FROM' and the next ';'

Comment: Look up how to use multiline records in sed. Good starting point http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-51b

Comment: sed is NOT for any job involving multiple lines. It is for simple subsitutions on a single line. For anything else an awk solution will be clearer, simpler, more robust and often briefer. If you find yourself looking for a tutorial to learn which sed command to use for a given task then you are using the wrong tool for that task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed ':load
# load any multiline sequence before going further
/;[[:space:]]*$/ !{ N;b load
   }

# from here you have a full (multi)line to treat
s/[[:space:]]\{1,\}FROM[[:space:]].*;/ ;/
   ' YourFile
```

You need to first load the multiline sequence before removing the end (sequence cycling in load section until a ended `;` is found)

- `:load` : address label for the 'goto' used later
- `/;[[:space:]]*$/`: when there is no ending `;` on the line (eventually some ending space later

  - `N`: load a new line in working buffer
  - `b load` : goto the label `load` (goto)
- `s/[[:space:]]\{1,\}FROM[[:space:]].*;/ ;/` change the whole current working buffer (so mono and multiline but all ending with `;`) with your new format. Sed in this case treat the buffer and not a line, New line are character like other in this case.

Last line need to be ended by `;` to be treated, if not, the last (uncomplete) sequence is lost

Comment: This works perfectly for me , but please , could you explain better what the syntax means? thanks

Comment: added in reply directly

Answer (score 2):

I think you can remove the '\n' in your script and then use sed to remove the from.

Eg

```
cat test.sql |tr -d '\n'|sed 's/FROM [^;]*;/;\n/g'
```

Comment: This solution does not work for me because I have more lines than "select from" the other lines that did not conform to the regular expression was printed on one line . But thanks , I learned that it serves "tr " :)

Answer (score 1):

awk is record-based, not line-based like sed, so it has no problem handling multi-line strings:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS=";"}{gsub(/FROM .*/,"")}1' file
SELECT value INTO val ;
SELECT value2 INTO val2 ;
```

The above just sets the Record Separator to a `;` instead of the default newline and operates on the resulting strings which can contain newlines just like any other characters.

Comment: This works too, but I want to use sed instead of awk. Also, this solution print ';' before '\n' so the ';' it's on a new line, but for the sql script funcionality works too. Thanks

Comment: I don't understand your comment about it printing `;` before `\n`. It produces exactly the output you show in your question from the input you show in your question. Using sed for this requires the use of constructs that became obsolete in the mid-1970s when awk was invented but feel free...

Comment: Sorry , I confused the language for a moment, I want to say `after` instead of `before`. Anyway on the code looks like this with your solution: `select * into val \n;`

Comment: This comment is for mention to you, look the previous comment @Ed

Comment: My script very simply treats newlines like any other character. It neither adds nor removes them individually and if there are any between `FROM` and `;` then they will be removed. Any remaining newlines present in the output were already present in your input. Run `cat -v` on your input to check for control chars (maybe control-Ms to be removed with dos2unix?). Copy/paste my solution again to make sure you didn't retype it and introduce a bug.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you either have to get rid of newline delimiters

```
tr -d '\n'
```

or use *Pythons* "re.M | re.DOTALL" arguments in re.compile

eg (roughly put):

```
pattern = re.compile('FROM[^;]*;', re.M | re.DOTALL)
result = re.findall(pattern, file)
```

Usually, when I needed to regex over newlines, I always ended up with Python. Bash is too newline based that it's hard to bend it to do this. 
But replacing a '\n' with a placeholder might suffice, if you really need to use bash.